# Haskell, compiler, enforcing the token order?

Tags: haskell

Could someone give me a small example how you can enforce the order of a language, using Haskell to write a basic compiler?

So for example, if I wanted to write a programming language in which "table bed lamp" was a valid string, but "bed lamp table" wasn't, how would I go about doing this?

If someone could point me in the right direction I think I could then extrapolate and understand this a lot more.

Thanks

Comment: This question is too simple to have an enlightening simplest answer. Here's a boring function that does exactly what you ask: `isValid s = s == "table bed lamp"`.

Answer (score 3):

you should check ressources about `parsers`. This is the part of a program which is responsible for analysing text, and building data from it. wikipedia entry:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing

In haskell, `Parsec` has a reputation of being a powerful library for writing a parser (I have never used it.)

http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Parsec

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have been asking a lot of very basic questions about compilers over the last few days.  Is it not better for you to pick up a textbook on compilers and get some grounding, first, before trying to proceed?  Appel's book "Modern compiler construction in ML" would be a good start, if you're trying to use Haskell as the language you write the compiler in.

Comment: I know how to write a compiler..... I don't know how to write a compiler in Haskell....

Comment: Also, if someone provided me with an answer to my basic question, then I can use this to extrapolate. Every haskel material I have only included calculator parsing examples....